# Select format of pasted images

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I often use the clipboard to paste screen captures into my HTML e-mail messages and crop them to remove unwanted parts. The feature is a great time saver.

Unluckily, Outlook chooses an overcompressed JPEG format to save the images:

[image: Sample]

Is it possible to reduce the compression ratio or, alternatively, use a lossless compression format such as PNG?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible using outlook (not with an extension/plugin at least. If you find out a way or somebody mentions it here, consider my answer an alternative because it's pretty annoying TBH).

I didn't understand if you want them to be in JPEG or it compresses them to JPEG but either way this should help you:

The images you can store in your clipboard are `.bmp` format (even if the original is in some other type of format).

What I would do is launch MS paint, paste it there, and save it as the format you desire, then insert it to your email.

---

After reading the comments and seeing the picture, my assumption is that it's a problem with your settings. I'll write a couple of steps you should take:

1. Replicate the problem
2. Select the image
3. Go to the `Format` tab.

[image: Compress Pictures Button]

4. Go to "Compress Pictures"

[image: Compress Pictures Dialog]

Now select `Use document resolution` (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>). You should also see if there's another option that pleases you more.

*P.S. The selected options in the screenshot are the default.*

Comment: Are you aware of some plugin? I like the `PrintScreen` plus `Ctrl+V` method because it's fast. My only complaint is that images are too pixelated.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Well first, are you sure it's compression? is it possible that you cropped, and then have resized the image to be bigger? I'm trying to replicate this situation.

Comment: I only crop and I get the classical JPEG artifacts. I'll upload a sample.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario That would be very beneficial, thank you.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I've edited the answer. See if it helps.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions but my ribbon does not have the same options than yours (which is probably a newer version). Also, I don't think it's a resolution problem at all: image is not resized or resampled, it's just saved as JPEG with a fixed compression ratio probably thought for photographs rather than screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the outlook mail server (at least in office 2010), it's with the outlook text editor.  Anytime an image is *modified using the outlook editor*, it will get automatically converted into a JPEG once sent.  But unaltered pngs that are pasted inline will be preserved, both in sending and receiving emails from outlook.

Here's a simple test of emails sent through the outlook client. Blurry is okay (since I've zoomed in a lot), but [artifacting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact) is not:

[image: demo]